# Pomagranate mead color

Tags: fermentation, mead, brewing

I've been fermenting my pomagranate mead for about 2 weeks now and I'm planning on racking it in a week. My question is why does my mead have a brown red color? Is this a normal colour for pomagranate mead. Is this brown colour from the honey or I added some grape tannin which had a brown colour ( I didn't add that much). I'm going to let if ferment more but I was just curious about the colour. Also is there a way to make it a darker red and less brown?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the answer lies in your question.

Pomagranate itself gives a red juice color. Honey is yellowish, it can be light or dark.  Grape tannin (the powder) is light brown.  Add Red + Yellow + Brown, and you get a red brownish mead.

To get a better color, I suggest adding some grapes that have a deep red color,  like Alicante Bouschet, to your recipe. If you can get some, you will need very little to change the color, so it should not change the taste of the mead too much.

I am not sure about other ways. I personally don't like adding food coloring, but it can work as well.

Comment: Unless your wine has a color characteristic that must be achieved, then color is a non-issue. Two characteristics are necessary are crystal clarity and more generally that it tastes nice.

Comment: I agree Escoce, it is cosmetics, but that **is** the question...

Answer (score 0):

I have some still pomegranate cyser that I have been aging for 6 months.  When it was in primary it had a murky red brown color to it.  After the fermentation process is complete the suspended yeast should start to settle out and begin clearing the liquid leaving a red coloring.  The long you let it age the clearer it will get.

I don't ad tannin to mine, so if the discoloration is from that I do not know what aging will do for you.